# JAVASCRIPT: replace iframe with new one or make new one if not exists

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, iframe

I need to replace iframe src acording to user input. I need some if else but not sure what to do with vars - I'm noob. Here is a code so far:

```html
<div>
            
            <h3>Some Header</h3>
            
<input type="text" size="25" id="inputTxt" value="">
<button onclick="myFunc()">go</button>
<br>
<br>

<div id="myDiv"></div>

<script>
function myFunc() {
            var word = document.getElementById("inputTxt").value;
            //if iframe (iframeClass) exists - replace with new one - else make new one...
            var someNewFrame = document.createElement("iframe");
            someNewFrame.setAttribute("class", "iframeClass");
            someNewFrame.setAttribute("src", "http://someones.com/next/staters/" + word );
            var newFrame = document.getElementById("myDiv");
            newFrame.appendChild(someNewFrame); 
}
</script>

            
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the content in the div. By removing the last child via `newFrame.removeChild(newFrame.lastChild);` you have cleared the div. After that you can easily add a new iframe

```js
function myFunc() {
        var word = document.getElementById("inputTxt").value;
        //if iframe (iframeClass) exists - replace with new one - else make new one...
        var someNewFrame = document.createElement("iframe");
        someNewFrame.setAttribute("class", "iframeClass");
        someNewFrame.setAttribute("src", "http://someones.com/next/staters/" + word );
        var newFrame = document.getElementById("myDiv");
        // remove the last child
        if(newFrame.lastChild!==null)
            newFrame.removeChild(newFrame.lastChild);
        newFrame.appendChild(someNewFrame); 
}
```

```html
<div>
            
        <h3>Some Header</h3>
        
<input type="text" size="25" id="inputTxt" value="">
<button onclick="myFunc()">go</button>
<br>
<br>

<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.....